# Modelling a closed kinematic chain in simscape

Tags: matlab, physics, simulink, modeling, simscape

I am trying to model a close kinematic chain in simulink. However the model fails to be created and i get the following error:

> *** Model not assembled: position violation ***

I am looking for any suggestions to get it working.

### Current modelling

I have the following link structure:

- MH

  - link11

    - link21
  - link12

    - link22

All the above joints are revolute joints (MH-link11,MH-link12,link11-link21,link12-link22).

**I want to connect link21 and link22**. I have found the exact intersection point and even used a transform sensor to compensate small errors (order of magnitude 1e-5). So the frames i want to attach match exactly.

The transform sensor gives me the following translation:
`[x,y,z] = [3.2594e-10,1.2520e-10,3.3367e-11]`

and the following axis and angle:
`axis: -z` , `angle = 67.329` (degrees).

The transform sensor measurement frame is the Base frame, and the sensor is in the following figure:

[image: Transform sensor]

### Closing the chain

So i add a revolute joint with a state target of `-67.329` degrees and low priority, seen below.
[image]

From the *mechanics explorer* tab, i see the base and follower frames of the revolute joint match the joint21_EE (B) and joint22_EE (F) frames exactly.

### What i tried

0. I followed this example: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/sm/ug/model-four-bar.html
   which says the following:

> In the Base-Crank Revolute Joint block dialog box, expand State Targets and select `Specify Position Target`.
>
> Specify the `Value` parameter as `-30` deg.
>
> For the Coupler-Rocker Revolute Joint block, in the `Z Revolute Primitive (Rz)` > `State Targets` section, select the `Specify Position Target` parameter, and specify the `Value` parameter as `0` deg and `Priority` parameter as `Low (approximate)`.
>
> On the Modeling tab of the Simulink® Toolstrip, click `Update Model`. Mechanics Explorer opens with a static display of the four-bar linkage in its initial configuration. The image shows the isometric view of the four-bar linkage.

1. Adding state targets (with high priority) to all joints. Then i get the error:

> Targets or motion inputs are specified for every joint around a kinematic loop:

2. Adding state targets to only one joint. Then i get the error:

> High priority position target +0 (deg) not achieved; actual value: -0.000717909 (deg) You can configure this diagnostic in the Simscape Multibody Configuration Parameters dialog.

3. Having no state target. Then i get the initial error.

### Extra info

- I use matlab R2022b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a while, i found the root of the problem.

In the mathworks [example](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/sm/ug/model-four-bar.html), the close chain can move in 2D. So, by trying to close the chain, the error was only in the relative angle. and thus a low priority angle was sufficient.
One can see that the angle error was quite large `103 degrees`:

[image: Angle error in example]

In my example, **the kinematic chain can move in 3D**, and thus kinematic loop errors are in `[x,y,z]` and `[Rx,Ry,Rz]`. So, to close the chain, i need a [bushing joint](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/sm/ref/bushingjoint.html), to add position targets for all directions/orientations apart `Rz`, to let it rotate.

[image: Bushing joint]